# Update Foreign Key

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys

I have to update a foreign key but i don't know exactly how it's done.
The following are my table:

```
CREATE TABLE `mydb`.`mannschaft` ( 
`mannschaftID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
`name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL , 
`stufe` INT NOT NULL,
`trainer` INT NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (`mannschaftID`),
FOREIGN KEY (`trainer`) REFERENCES `trainer`(`trainerID`),
FOREIGN KEY (`stufe`) REFERENCES `stufe`(`stufeID`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_german1_ci;

CREATE TABLE `mydb`.`spieler` ( 
`spielerID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
`name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL , 
`vorname` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,  
`jahrgang` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL ,
`bemerkung` VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
`mannschaft` INT NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (`spielerID`),
FOREIGN KEY (`mannschaft`) REFERENCES `mannschaft` (`mannschaftID`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_german1_ci;
```

if i do:

```
SHOW CREATE table course;
```

i get the following:

```
CREATE TABLE `spieler` (
 `spielerID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(50) COLLATE latin1_german1_ci NOT NULL,
 `vorname` varchar(50) COLLATE latin1_german1_ci NOT NULL,
 `jahrgang` varchar(10) COLLATE latin1_german1_ci NOT NULL,
 `bemerkung` varchar(300) COLLATE latin1_german1_ci NOT NULL,
 `mannschaft` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`spielerID`),
 KEY `mannschaft` (`mannschaft`),
 CONSTRAINT `spieler_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`mannschaft`) REFERENCES `mannschaft` (`mannschaftID`),
 CONSTRAINT `spieler_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`mannschaft`) REFERENCES `mannschaft` (`mannschaftID`),
 CONSTRAINT `spieler_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`mannschaft`) REFERENCES `mannschaft` (`mannschaftID`),
 CONSTRAINT `spieler_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`mannschaft`) REFERENCES `mannschaft` (`mannschaftID`),
 CONSTRAINT `spieler_ibfk_5` FOREIGN KEY (`mannschaft`) REFERENCES `mannschaft` (`mannschaftID`),
 CONSTRAINT `spieler_ibfk_6` FOREIGN KEY (`mannschaft`) REFERENCES `mannschaft`     (`mannschaftID`),
 CONSTRAINT `spieler_ibfk_7` FOREIGN KEY (`mannschaft`) REFERENCES `mannschaft` (`mannschaftID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1     COLLATE=latin1_german1_ci
```

I like to do this sql:

```
    $sql = "UPDATE `spieler` SET `mannschaft` = '0' WHERE `spielerID` = '".$id."'";
```

but i get this error:

```
    Error deleting record: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mydb`.`spieler`, CONSTRAINT `spieler_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`mannschaft`) REFERENCES `mannschaft` (`mannschaftID`))
```

i think i have to delete the key and then update the field and after create it again?
How can i do this?
Thanks

Comment: If you want to have `spieler` entries that are not associated with any `mannschaft` entry, make the `mannschaft` field nullable and update your `spieler` entry with `SET mannschaft = NULL`. The error message just tells you that there is not entry in `mannschaft` table that has the id `0`

Comment: @BenjaminPaap Thanks for the fast reply. Very simple solution, I have not even thought about this. I will try that as soon as possible.

Comment: @BenjaminPaap finally had time to test it and it works like a charm, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment from @BenjaminPaap solved the issue for me.